# How can I POST a simple HTML form in R?

Tags: html, r, post, rcurl, rvest

I'm relatively new to R programming and I'm trying to put some of the stuff I'm learning in the Johns Hopkins Data Science track to practical use.  Specifically, I would like to automate the process of downloading historical bond prices from the [US Treasury website](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/GA-FI/FedInvest/selectSecurityPriceDate.htm)

Using both Firefox and R, I was able to determine that the US Treasury website uses a very simple HTML POST form to specify a single date for the quotes of interest.  It then returns a table of secondary market information for all outstanding bonds.

I have unsuccessfully tried to use two different R packages to submit a request to the US Treasury web server.  Hare are the two approaches I tried:

Attempt #1 (using RCurl):

```
url <- "https://www.treasurydirect.gov/GA-FI/FedInvest/selectSecurityPriceDate.htm"
td.html <- postForm(url,
                    submit = "Show Prices",
                    priceDate.year  = 2014,
                    priceDate.month = 12,
                    priceDate.day   = 15,
                   .opts = curlOptions(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))
```

This results in a web page being returned and stored in `td.html` but all it contains is an error message from the treasurydirect server.  I know the server is working because when I submit the same request via my browser, I get the expected results.

Attempt #2 (using rvest):

```
s <- html_session(url)
f0 <- html_form(s)
f1 <- set_values(f0[[2]], priceDate.year=2014, priceDate.month=12, priceDate.day=15)
test <- submit_form(s, f1)
```

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't even leave R and results in the following error message from R:

```
Submitting with 'submit'
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : <url> malformed
```

I can't seem to figure out how to see what "malformed" text is being sent to rvest so that I can try to diagnose the problem.

Any suggestions or tips to solving this seeming simple task would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: The error message from the US Treasury server was a very unhelpful:  "An unexpected error has occurred. Please Try Again Later"

Comment: The plain **rvest** approach now works fine without errors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, it appears to work with the `httr` library.

```
library(httr)

url <- "https://www.treasurydirect.gov/GA-FI/FedInvest/selectSecurityPriceDate.htm"

fd <- list(
    submit = "Show Prices",
    priceDate.year  = 2014,
    priceDate.month = 12,
    priceDate.day   = 15
)

resp<-POST(url, body=fd, encode="form")
content(resp)
```

The `rvest` library is really just a wrapper to `httr`. It looks like it doesn't do a good job of interpreting absolute URLs without the server name. So if you look at

```
f1$url
# [1] /GA-FI/FedInvest/selectSecurityPriceDate.htm
```

you see that it just has the path and not the server name. This appears to be confusing `httr`. If you do

```
f1 <- set_values(f0[[2]], priceDate.year=2014, priceDate.month=12, priceDate.day=15)
f1$url <- url
test <- submit_form(s, f1)
```

that seems to work. Perhaps it's a bug that should be reported to `rvest`. (Tested on `rvest_0.1.0`)

Comment: Awesome!!!  Thanks for the quick reply.  Your httr solution works great and I get the results I wanted.  I'm not familiar enough with rvest to feel comfortable submitting a bug report.  BTW, your "fix" for rvest was successful, but I chose to use your httr solution because it was easier to use the results.

Comment: @MrFlick Many thanks! I had the same problem with another login form and your description solved it. I just opened a [rvest issue](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/issues/52) and referenced this SO post.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but adding the

```
style='POST'
```

parameter to `postForm` does the trick as well.