# Submit form with no submit button in rvest

Tags: r, web-crawler, rvest

I'm trying write a crawler to download some information, similar to [this Stack Overflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418770/using-rvest-or-httr-to-log-in-to-non-standard-forms-on-a-webpage)  The answer is useful for creating the filled-in form, but I'm struggling to find a way to submit the form when a submit button is not part of the form.  Here is an example:

```
session <- html_session("www.chase.com")
form <- html_form(session)[[3]]

filledform <- set_values(form, `user_name` = user_name, `usr_password` = usr_password)
session <- submit_form(session, filledform)
```

At this point, I receive this error:

```
Error in names(submits)[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

How can I make this form submit?

Comment: I also would like to understand how to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a dirty hack that works for me: After studying the [`submit_form` source code](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/blob/c953df459ce0774b8702b8f46580d6bc169a8c26/R/form.R), I figured that I could work around the problem by injecting a fake submit button into my code version of the form, and then the `submit_form` function would call that. It works, except that it gives a warning that often lists an inappropriate input object (not in the example below, though). However, despite the warning, the code works for me:

```
session <- html_session("www.chase.com")
form <- html_form(session)[[3]]

# Form on home page has no submit button,
# so inject a fake submit button or else rvest cannot submit it.
# When I do this, rvest gives a warning "Submitting with '___'", where "___" is
# often an irrelevant field item.
# This warning might be an rvest (version 0.3.2) bug, but the code works.
fake_submit_button <- list(name = NULL,
                           type = "submit",
                           value = NULL,
                           checked = NULL,
                           disabled = NULL,
                           readonly = NULL,
                           required = FALSE)
attr(fake_submit_button, "class") <- "input"
form[["fields"]][["submit"]] <- fake_submit_button

user_name <- "user"
usr_password <- "password"

filledform <- set_values(form, `user_name` = user_name, `usr_password` = usr_password)
session <- submit_form(session, filledform)
```

The successful result displays the following warning, which I simply ignore:

```
> Submitting with 'submit'
```

Comment: Clever solution.  I'd be interested to know whether the warning is indeed a bug, or if it's the intended behavior.

Comment: I'm not seeing this warning with the recent version