# Submitting form to Web of Knowledge using R and rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm interested in scraping titles of journals from [Web of Knowledge](http://isiknowledge.com/wos) using `R`and `rvest`. However, I'm having problems submitting the proper form. I'm interested in a list of all Econometrica articles from 1960-1970. I'm automatically logged in using access from my local university library.

When I run

```
library("rvest")
library("httr")
link = "http://isiknowledge.com/wos"
form = html_session(link) %>% html_form() # returns list of 6 forms
form[[4]] = set_values(form[[4]], # set values in form number 4
    product = "WOS",
    range = "ALL",
    action = "search",
    period = "Range Selection", 
    startYear = "1960",
    endYear = "1970",
    range = "ALL",
    'value(select1)' = "SO",
    'value(input1)' = "econometrica",
    formUpdated = "TRUE") 

submit_form(html_session(link), form = form)
```

I have two problems: First, it submits with `''` and not "Econometrica", and second, I receive the following error message: `Error in if (!(submit %in% names(submits))) { : argument is of length zero`.

There's a Python alternative [here](https://github.com/kousu/isi/blob/master/isi_scrape.py) but the code has to be in R. Any help on how to make progress would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar trouble with ISI pages, and the problem was that they at least sometimes design their forms with no submit buttons (submission is handled using JavaScript). I examined [the link you posted](http://isiknowledge.com/wos), and that seems to be the case with the fourth form on that page (though I'm not sure if the search image serves as a submit button).

If this is the problem, then my answer to the question "[Submit form with no submit button in rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38387063/2449926)" might provide the solution for your case.

In brief, you can inject a submit button into your version of the code and then submit that. Details of how to do that are in the linked post.