# add new field to form with rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to download [the full] dynamically expanded [holdings] table using rvest, but am getting an `Unknown field names` error.

```
s <- html_session("http://innovatoretfs.com/etf/?ticker=ffty")
f <- html_form(s)[[1]]
#the following line fails:
f.new <- set_values(f, `__EVENTTARGET` = "ctl00$BodyPlaceHolder$ViewHoldingsLinkButton")

##subsequent lines are not tested##
doc <- submit_form(s, f.new)
tabs <- xml_find_all(doc, "//table")
holdings <- html_table(tabs, fill = T, trim = T)[[5]]
```

I'm not great with HTML/HTTP but from what i can chase through, it seems to me that to expand the table requires a postback of the form with this new field value set

after inspecting the `set_values` function, it seems that it only allows existing fields to be assigned values.

is there any way to add a new field to a form under `rvest`? If not, is anyone ware of another package I could use to get this functionality?

[edited] to be very explicit that i need the full version of the dynamically expanded table and to add expected subsequent table extraction code

Comment: Are you trying to scrape the ETF table over time? (The Growth of $10,000 table)

Comment: You could also try RSelenium to scrape the table(s)

Comment: @papelr no. i'm trying to scrape the FULL holdings table

Comment: @papelr thank for the pointer to [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/). unfortunately, it looks like its on a unmaintained path

Comment: I would take the solution below and ask another SO question on how to get the full table... But I'm also like 80% certain someone is gonna tell you to go the RSelenium route

Comment: The fact that RSelenium did not work ticked me off so much I posted another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51353272/rselenium-scraping-a-full-expandable-table @Ethan

Answer (score 2):

**DISGUSTING, BUT WORKS** could probably be cleaned up, but will submit an issue to the project for a proper fix for add_values type functionality

```
getInnovatorHoldings <- function() {
    s <- html_session("http://innovatoretfs.com/etf/?ticker=ffty")
    f <- html_form(s)[[1]]
    f.new <- add_values(f,
                            `__EVENTTARGET` = "ctl00$BodyPlaceHolder$ViewHoldingsLinkButton",
                            `__EVENTARGUMENT` = "",
                            `submit` = NULL)

    s <- submit_form(s, f.new, "submit")
    doc <- read_html(s)
    tabs <- xml_find_all(doc, "//table")
    holdings <- html_table(tabs, fill = T, trim = T)[[5]]
    return(holdings)
}

add_values <- function(form, ...) {
    new_values <- list(...)
    no_match <- which(!names(new_values) %in% names(form$fields))
    for (n in no_match) {
        if (names(new_values[n]) == "submit") {
            form$fields[[names(new_values[n])]] <- new_input(name = names(new_values[n]), type = "submit", value = NULL)
        } else {
            form$fields[[names(new_values[n])]] <- new_input(name = names(new_values[n]), type = "hidden", value = new_values[n][[1]])
        }
    }
    return(form)
}

new_input <- function(name, type, value, checked = NULL, disabled = NULL, readonly = NULL, required = F) {
    return(
        structure(
            list(name = name,
                type = type,
                value = value,
                checked = checked,
                disabled = disabled,
                readonly = readonly,
                required = required
                ),
            class = "input"
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: I'm hoping for a wayyy simpler RSelenium fix...will update my answer when that comes around

Comment: borrowed submit button solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885629/submit-form-with-no-submit-button-in-rvest?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

**Answer: rvest**

This solution works, but only returns the first 10 rows of the table:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

ffty_url <- "http://innovatoretfs.com/etf/?ticker=ffty"

ffty_table <- ffty_url %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_table(fill = T) %>% 
  .[[5]]
```

Working on getting the full table, but that may not be possible using `rvest` because it is expandable. Honestly not sure.

---

**Answer: RSelenium**

You're going to have to install `RSelenium` and docker, and there are multiple tutorials on that. **BUT** the following code also only returns the first ten rows, which has me **livid**.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L, remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
                  browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://innovatoretfs.com/etf/?ticker=ffty")
page <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
table <- html_table(page, fill = TRUE, header = T)
table[[5]]
```

If anyone wants to expand on either sets of code, please...