# RSelenium: scraping a FULL expandable table

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

Based off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352697/add-new-field-to-form-with-rvest/51352962#51352962) question, the OP wants to scrape the table "All Holdings," from this [page](http://innovatoretfs.com/etf/?ticker=ffty#holdings) - scroll down to the yellow part. The table shows the first 10 rows, but can expand to quite a few more.

Both of my `rvest` and `RSelenium` solutions only take the first 10 rows, when we want the entire table. My code:

**rvest code**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

etf_url <- "http://innovatoretfs.com/etf/?ticker=ffty"

etf_table <- etf_url %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_table(fill = T) %>% 
  .[[5]]
```

**RSelenium code**

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L, remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
                  browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://innovatoretfs.com/etf/?ticker=ffty")
page <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
table <- html_table(page, fill = TRUE, header = T)
table[[5]]
```

How can we get the FULL table? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should expand the table - didn't test it in Selenium but it should work.

```
remDr$executeScript("__doPostBack('ctl00$BodyPlaceHolder$ViewHoldingsLinkButton','')", args = list())
```

Comment: Awesome - where should that placed in the script above? Under the `remDr$navigate` argument?

Comment: It returned: `Selenium message:unknown error: 'args' must be a list
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs x86_64)

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
   Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
  Further Details: run errorDetails method`

Comment: I have updated my answer - args were missing from executeScript call. Check if that resolves the issue. Unfortunately I cannot check it myself as installing RSelenium is a pain and I don't have time to fight with it currently.

Comment: Still returns the same error message, unfortunately. Oh well