# With rvest, how to extract html contents from the object returned by submit_form()

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, html-parsing, rvest

I am trying to download some traffic data from pems.dot.ca.gov, following [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418770/using-rvest-or-httr-to-log-in-to-non-standard-forms-on-a-webpage).

```
rm(list=ls())
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(httr)
url <- "http://pems.dot.ca.gov/?report_form=1&dnode=tmgs&content=tmg_volumes&tab=tmg_vol_ts&export=&tmg_station_id=74250&s_time_id=1369094400&s_time_id_f=05%2F21%2F2013&e_time_id=1371772740&e_time_id_f=06%2F20%2F2013&tod=all&tod_from=0&tod_to=0&dow_5=on&dow_6=on&tmg_sub_id=all&q=obs_flow&gn=hour&html.x=34&html.y=8"
pgsession <- html_session(url)
pgform <-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
filled_form <- set_values(pgform,
                          'username' = 'omitted',
                          'password' = 'omitted')
resp = submit_form(pgsession, filled_form)
resp_2 = resp$response
cont = resp_2$content
```

I checked the `class()` of these items and found that the resp is a 'session', resp_2 is a 'response', and cont is 'raw'. My question is: how can I extract the html content correctly so that I can proceed with XPath to pick out the actual data I want from this page? My intuition is that I should parse the resp_2 which is a response, but I just can not make it work. Your help are highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at Selector Gadget? I find it useful for finding specific parts of a web page that I want to extract. http://selectorgadget.com/ . It works well with `html_nodes` and `html_text` within `rvest`

Comment: I just looked into the gadget and it seems cool. But my question is not about how to select stuff from html , it's about how to convert the response or the raw into html. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: It appears the site requires a username and password to get past the opening screen.  You code code above uses "omitted" which is not a valid combination.  If you can post an example of the actual page which you are interested in, it would be more helpful.

Comment: @Dave2e I used my login credentials in my code. I just didn't show them here in stackoverflow:) sorry about making the code not reproducible. I hope someone can give me hints on how to deal with the response or raw. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
pg <- content(resp$response)

html_nodes(pg, "table.inlayTable") %>% 
  html_table() -> tab

head(tab[[1]])
##                 X1      X2           X3           X4
## 1                          Data Quality Data Quality
## 2             Hour 8 Lanes   % Observed  % Estimated
## 3 05/24/2013 00:00   1,311           50            0
## 4 05/24/2013 01:00     729           50            0
## 5 05/24/2013 02:00     399           50            0
## 6 05/24/2013 03:00     487           50            0
```

(you'll obviously need to modify the column names)

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you @hrbrmstr, for answering this question and for getting your own login credentials :)

Comment: How did you know about the 'table.inlayTable' setting?  It is really cool!  When I Google this phrase, only two results were returned! Amazing that you know about it!

Comment: I guessed you needed the table on that page and that's the CSS selector for it. If you're going to scrape things from the web you need to read up on either CSS selectors or XPath selectors and get familiar with browser "Developer Tools"

Answer (score 2):

You need `httr::content`, which parses a response into content, which in this case is HTML that can easily be parsed with `rvest`:

```
resp_2 %>% content()
## {xml_document}
## <html style="height: 100%">
## [1] <head>\n  <!-- public -->\n  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/     ## ...
## [2] <body class="yui-skin-sam public">\n  <div id="maincontainer" style="height: 100%">\n\n      \n\     ## ...
```

Comment: Hi @alistaire, I think that's what I need. Thank you! How do I print the whole <body> section to the console so I can take a close look at it?

Comment: `harvest::html_structure` can give you a quick look at the DOM, if you need.

Comment: You can also parse as text and use `cat` to print (since it will be a long single string, the default print method will truncate): `resp_2 %>% content(as = 'text') %>% cat()`. While that's a nice way to see what you have, the default parsed version is better for extracting the parts you want (though you could get back to it by calling `read_html` on the text).

Comment: And the first comment above was supposed to say `rvest::html_structure`, obviously. Autocorrect, sorry.