# how to reuse a session to avoid repeated login when scraping with rvest?

Tags: r, session, web-scraping, rvest

I developed some codes to scraping traffic data based [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687068/with-rvest-how-to-extract-html-contents-from-the-object-returned-by-submit-form/38689396?noredirect=1#comment64774034_38689396).I need to scrape many pages after log in, but right now my codes seem repeatedly log in the site for each url. How can I ‘reuse’ the session to avoid repeated log in so that, hopefully, the codes can run faster? Here's the pseudo-code:

```
generateURL <- function(siteID){return siteURL}

scrapeContent <- function(siteURL, session, filled_form){return content}

mainPageURL <- 'http://pems.dot.ca.gov/'
pgsession <- html_session(mainPageURL)
pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
filled_form <- set_value(pgform, 'username'='myUserName', 'password'='myPW')

siteIDList = c(1,2,3)
vectorOfContent <- vector(mode='list', length=3) #to store all the content

i=1
for (siteID in siteIDList){
    url = generateURL(siteID)
    content = scrapeContent(url, pgsession, filled_form)
    vectorOfContent[[i]]=content
    i = i +1}
```

I read the rvest documnentation but there is no such details in it. My question: How can I ‘reuse’ the session to avoid repeated log in? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
require(rvest)
pgsession <- html_session(mainPageURL)
pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
filled_form <- set_value(pgform, 'username'='myUserName', 'password'='myPW')
s <- submit_form(pgsession, pgform) # s is your logged in session

vectorOfContent <- vector(mode='list', length=3)

for (siteID in siteIDList){
  url <- generateURL(siteID)
  # jump_to navigates within the session, read_html parses the html
  vectorOfContent[[siteID]]=s %>% jump_to(generateURL) %>% read_html()
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! The jump_to() is essentially what I am looking for. Sorry for the late response.