# Scrape date from banned.video website using R

Tags: r, rvest

Having trouble scraping the date on this website (https://www.banned.video/watch?id=623387f694e6ee018c5765dd). It's for research purposes. My code is:

`rvest::read_html("https://www.banned.video/watch?id=623387f694e6ee018c5765dd") %>%  rvest::html_nodes(".css-462lap")`

Any ideas are appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40275000/6574038

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't need to login, I need to pull the date.

Comment: Indeed, probably I pasted the wrong link, now its gone :/ I noticed there's some querying going on `?id=...` maybe that's the issue. Perhaps look into `rvest::html_session`.