# Web Scraping Capital Bikeshare personal trip history data in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape my trip history data on Capital Bikeshare Website. I have to log in and go to the trips menu to see the data. but i get this error:

```
> `No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readHTMLTable’ for signature ‘"xml_document"’
```

Here's my code.

```
> library(httr)
> library(XML)
> handle <- handle("https://www.capitalbikeshare.com/")
> path <-"profile/trips"

> login <- list( profile_login="myemail", profile_pass ="mypassword", profile_redirect_url="https://secure.capitalbikeshare.com/profile/trips/QNURCMF2Q6")
> response <- POST(handle = handle, path = path, body = login)
> readHTMLTable(content(response))
```

I also tried using [rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418770/using-rvest-or-httr-to-log-in-to-non-standard-forms-on-a-webpage) but then I kept getting the "`Error: Unknown field names: _username, _password`" error. Which field should I use here? I tried Id, name, etc and still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start the member login page is different than the intro page which you have listed above:

This may not be correct but try this as a possible rvest starting point:

```
login<-"https://secure.capitalbikeshare.com/profile/login"

library(rvest)
pgsession<-html_session(login)
pgform<-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
#update user id and password in the next line
filled_form<-set_values(pgform, "_username"="myemail@gmail.com", "_password"="password")
submit_form(pgsession, filled_form)
```

Once you login in then one can use the jump_to function to move to the desired pages:

```
page<-jump_to(pgsession, newurl) #newurl will be the address where to go to next.
```

Hope this helps, if this does not work, leave a comment and I'll delete the post.

Comment: I get this error `Error in xml2::url_absolute(url, x$url) : object 'newurl' not found` after `page<-jump_to(pgsession, newurl) `

Comment: @jso1226, If you got this far the login step worked.  Sorry, I should have been clearer, "newurl" will be the url to the page you wish go to. When I have done similar steps I have to predefine this URL earlier in my code.

Comment: I don't get the error anymore and it seems like it went through but would I need to run another command? i wanted to see if it will give me the fields that i'm supposed to see, such as trip information and duration. So i ran `summary(page)' `but it gives me a table of handle, config, url, back, forward, response and html in rows with length, class and mode as columns.

Comment: Yes, correct, now since you jumped to the new  page you will need to parse the webpage with the html_nodes function.  Please see the documentation associated with the rvest package for more help.

Comment: Thank you @Dave2e!